# Adding group of Dictionary value together

Tags: python-3.x, loops, dictionary

I try to do loop of dictionaries. 
For example

```
A = {"Name":1,"Price":2}
B = {"Name":3,"Price":6}
C = {"Name":"","Price":3}
```

I want add A B and C together

```
C = {"Name":[1,3,],"Price":[2,6,3]}
```

How can I do this?Thanks 
This is my actual code I try to grab data from accommodation page. It still missing the part where I put all dictionary of data together and loop for the next page and thank you again by the way.

```
            from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup 
            import re
            from selenium import webdriver
            driver = webdriver.Firefox()
            my_url = 'https://www.hipflat.co.th/en/search/sale/condo_y/any_r1/any_r2/any_p/any_b/any_a/any_w/any_o/any_i/100.62442610451406,13.77183154691727_c/12_z/list_v'
            driver.get(my_url)
            html = driver.page_source
            page_soup = soup(html)
            #Grab Condo
            Condo = page_soup.findAll("li",{"class":"listing"})
            for Con in Condo:
                Name = Con.findAll("div",{"class":"listing-project"})[0].text.strip()
                Description = Con.p.text
                Price = Con.findAll("div",{"class":"listing-price"})[0].text.strip()
                Type = Con.findAll("ul",{"class":"listing-detail"})[0].text.replace("\n","")
                Type = [Name]+[Price]+[Description]+re.split(r'(bed|bath|m2)',Type) 
                Data = {"Name" : Name,"Description" : Description,"Price":Price,"Bed":Type[3],"Bath":Type[5],"Area(m2)":Type[7],"Floor":Type[9]}
                print(Data)
            next_page = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="page-content"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[3]/a[1]').click()
```

Comment: only 2, or can there be more dictionaries?

Comment: ok I guess the edit answers me

Comment: Well I'm gonna do loop adding many dictionaries into one

Comment: I try to add this to the data but it didn't work                                                                                                   
                                                                                                               
    Whole = []
    Whole = [[Whole]+[Data]]

Comment: I get the dictionary part already. Still, I can't figure out on how to loop page without breaking it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic approach to combine dicts like that is, to check if the key is in the result dict, if yes, add the value to the list, otherwise if the key doesn't exist, you add a new list with the value.

```
result = {}

for dicti in (A, B, C):
    for key, value in dicti.items():
        if key in result:
            result[key].append(value)
        else:
            result[key] = [value]
```

The modern way to do this is, to use a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) with `list` passed as the `default_factory` function. It does basically the same as above and inserts a new list with the value if the key is missing.

```
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(list)

for dicti in (A, B, C):
    for key, value in dicti.items():
        result[key].append(value)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over the keys (of one of them).

```
indicts = [{}, {}...]
outdict = {}
for k in indicts[0].keys():
    outdict[k] = [d[k] for d in indicts]
```